# Unzip z01, z02, zip file in python

Tags: python, zip

Currently, I have a big zip file splited into 3 file test.zip, test.z01, test.zip02

I use zipfile library in python to extract these file, but encounter the

```
error: "BadZipFile: Bad magic number for file header"
```

---

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip","r") as file:
    file.extractall(folder_path)
```

Anyone know how to extract these file with Python.

Comment: The standard `zipfile` module does not handle multi-part archives. Which OS are you using? You might be able to "shell out" to execute an external program to perform the extraction.

Comment: I'm currently using windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling command line interfare of 7zip/winrar in python should solve this problems

```
import subprocess
unzip_command = '"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"' +  ' e ' + '"' + folder_path + '"'
subprocess.run(unzip_command, shell = True, cwd = folder_path)
```

The code above will extract all file in folder_path folder and store the file in this